# Arping for local broadcast address

Tags: ipv4, arp, broadcast

Given the local IP-network 10.173.128.0/24

I am looking at a wireshark and there is an ARP for 10.173.128.255.

- Why would a network client ever ARP for a broadcast address?
- Does this indicate a misconfigured network client?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

> Given the local IP-network 10.173.128.0/24
>
> I am looking at a wireshark and there is an ARP for 10.173.128.255.
>
> - Why would a network client ever ARP for a broadcast address?

A misconfigured mask on the client (for instance the client has a /23 mask instead of a /24) is one possible reason

> - Does this indicate a misconfigured network client?

That's certainly not the only reason... Another possible reason is a human could manually generate the ARP as well for a number of reasons which are not worth speculating about.

Comment: Misconfiguring the subnet mask on a client and manually crafting an ARP request like this... those really are the only ways I can envision this happening.  A correctly configured client will identify the broadcast address as a broadcast, not unicast, which is where ARP is used.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the most likely culprit is gratuitous ARP and that's how Wireshark reports the IP. Look at the end of the examples section on this page:

https://wiki.wireshark.org/Gratuitous_ARP